# Table insert value gets masked (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle DB.

When I insert into my table, one of the column's value gets masked for some reason and I don't know why? I googled this issue and I can't see any issue similar to this.

For example,

When I do the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
VALUES (123, 'Hello Customer, your bill is ready to view.');
```

The `Hello`, gets masked like the following, `"** masked ** Customer, your bill is ready to view."`

Comment: Presumably there is an insert trigger on the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I looked at the following 'select * from user_triggers' and it returned empty results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Grammar nazi lol :). I have edited it.

Comment: @Luffy : Also query `dba_triggers, all_triggers`.

Comment: Ty, it was due to a trigger. If you want to place that as an answer I will accept